# Is matplotlib 3.1.1 full backwards compatible with matplotlib 2.2.4?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some legacy code that creates plots with matplotlib 2.2.4. For new code, I use some new features of matplotlib 3.1.1, but I don't know if it will cause problems with my legacy code. Do you know if matplotlib 3.1.1 is fully backwards compatible with matplotlib 2.2.4?

Updating without knowing is not an option for me because I cannot mess up plots that already go directly to some clients.

The new feature from 3.1.1 version that I'm using is Zoom region inset axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0, 10)
Y1 = np.sin(x) + x + np.random.randn(50)
Y2 = np.sin(x) + 0.4 + np.random.randn(50)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y1,X,Y2)

axins = ax.inset_axes([0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2])
axins.plot(X,Y1,X,Y2)

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 1, 0, 2
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins)
```

I expect full compatibility with all commands available in 2.2.4 version in the 3.1.1, however, I want to know if someone has had any issue experience or know something about it.

Comment: Assuming that you set the RC parameter defaults to "classic" mode, you should be *mostly* good. Some API calls may have changes slightly/been deprecated/been removed, but you can catch those pretty easily with a test run. The rest *should* *in theory* be the same.

Comment: There are always some changes between versions, so you will never have "full compatibility". You find all API changes in [API changes](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html) and in the link to "old API changes" within.

Comment: Also, clauses 4, 5 in the [License](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/LICENSE/LICENSE) are relevant, but not a direct answer.

Comment: That being said, I don't see any issue with the specific commands you show here, again, assuming you set up rcparams correctly.

Comment: In general, the only way to know is to run your code (in a test environment), see if the output matches. If not, tweak it to match, possibly with `if mpl.__version__` statements.

Comment: Unless you are doing something truly arcane, you will *probably* have no major issues.

Comment: Are you using version control? Virtual environments?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not using virtual environment. There is a plan to have it, but not too soon.

Comment: Your best bet is to integrate the two code bases in a separate branch and test it in a dedicated venv. You can set one up locally just for you in a few minutes with a good tutorial. 99% chance it'll work with some minor tweaks. Even if not, no harm done since everthing was isolated.

Comment: Would you like me to write an answer explaining all this?

Answer (score 0):

**Intro**

In general, there is no such thing as perfect compatibility between versions. However, it is likely that for many use cases, the backwards-compatibility will be effectively complete. You can only know by actually trying with your exact code-base. The overview below will not guarantee that you will have a perfect transition, but will likely help you smooth out any differences.

> Updating without knowing is not an option for me because I cannot mess up plots that already go directly to some clients.

Keep in mind that the only real cutoff for knowing is before you send plots to your clients. You have the freedom to regenerate and inspect all those plots locally with the new version. What you are looking for is basically a regression test of the code, probably with a visual inspection as the test criterion.

**Changes**

There are two major changes that occurred during the transitions between version 1 and 2, and subsequently 2 and 3 of matplotlib: API changes, and style changes. Both are  exhaustively documented, as you would expect from a mature library like matplotlib.

**API**

The API changes are documented here: https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html. Given the code you show, I would not expect any major incompatibilities. One change that I have noticed is that the new API actually catches improper keyword arguments, instead of allowing them to pass through. This is an easy fix, described below.

**Style**

Style changes are documented here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/dflt_style_changes.html. In my experience, these have a more significant impact on transitioning from old code. For example, line colors and default selection of axis limits has changed from version 1 to version 2.

Aside from preserving your rcparams using the version 2 stylesheet, you may have to go through and tweak some small things like [`Formatter`s and `Locator`s](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html) here and there. Here is a link to manipulating styles: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html.

**Testing**

The simplest way to get your code working is to integrate the old code base in an isolated virtual environment, in a dedicated branch. I will assume that you have version control that supports the latter. You can follow any decent tutorial to get set up with venv very quickly, like here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/. Alternatively, you can go with something heavier, like conda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html.

In any case, you can have an environment that belongs only to you, has the right version of Python and Matplotlib, and does not affect any other code anywhere else to test in. Once you have generated all the plots you need to your satisfaction, you can merge the branch with the integrated code back into whatever branch(s) it needs to go into, and optionally delete the virtual environment you created.

**Random Thoughts**

Unless there are some very specific contractual obligations involved, some changes to your plots may be a good thing. You can always run things by your clients for approval. The important thing is of course to first understand how to get identical plots with the new version before you start tweaking things for "improvement".

**Conclusion**

While this approach will almost certainly yield the results you want, there are no guarantees in this life. Clauses 4 and 5 in the matplotlib [LICENSE file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/LICENSE/LICENSE) capture this uncertainty. However, I have a hard time imagining matplotlib v2 code that you will not be able to tweak into behaving exactly as you want in v3. You will never know how easy it is until you try. While the linked change documents can prepare you, there really is no knowing for sure ahead of time. Good luck!

Comment: "there is no such thing as perfect compatibility between versions" Yes, there is. Imagine a new version where the only API change was to add an optional argument to a function, with the default being the old behavior. This literally guarantees that no code using the old version will have different outputs with the new version. There are varying interpretations of what "backwards compatibility" means (e.g. can there be changes to output as long as nothing breaks?) but the statement that it doesn't exist is throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @zmbc What about the next sentence?

Comment: I think you didn't read any part of my answer except that one sentence.

Comment: I came to this question to learn the answer to a simple question: what versioning policy does matplotlib use? What changes do they consider "breaking" and what parts of the version string indicate the potential for breaking changes? For example, do they follow SemVer?

Comment: The question asks whether matplotlib (in the versions specified) is *fully* backwards compatible. Saying compatibility is "effectively complete" is another way of saying: no. But I interpreted your answer to be saying something further: that it would be unreasonable to ever expect actual, full backwards compatibility. It is very reasonable to expect this; it seems that matplotlib in general does not provide it (even for patch releases).

Comment: Apologies if I've misinterpreted your answer!

Comment: @zmbc. I didn't realize that that was your concern. Generally, matplotlib is fairly backwards compatible. Keep in mind that OP is trying to jump one major version. So clearly in that case the answer will be "no" virtually by definition. Between patches, the answer has generally been "yes". Your code should work within any major release number, and with few exceptions will look about the same.

Comment: Right, but note that what I came here to learn was about _policy_. I realize that the OP didn't ask about policies, but if there was a Matplotlib policy, I'd expect it to be cited here.

Comment: I've gathered now that Matplotlib has no versioning policy at all (there is no upgrade they guarantee will be backwards compatible). IMHO, stating this fact would be helpful addition to this answer. Perhaps it is what you intended with "there is no such thing as perfect compatibility between versions," but the common sense interpretation of that sentence is precisely the opposite: that such a policy could not exist even in principle.

Comment: @zmbc. I've had very few problems with matplotlib in this regard, and I've been using if for a large number of years. They use semantic versioning and try to stick with it. Anecdotally, I've had more version compatibility problems with libraries that insist heavily on a policy instead of just paying attention to their work.

Comment: Matplotlib uses semantic versioning? I can't find any evidence of this, and indeed your answer seems to contradict it. [The SemVer standard states](https://semver.org/): "Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backward incompatible changes are introduced to the public API."

Comment: That is fair, and it is all fine and good as long as you are an individual using matplotlib. If you are a package author _depending_ on matplotlib, it is critical to know the versioning _policy_ so you can predict which not-yet-released versions will be compatible with your software. This is laid out well in the "Introduction" section of the SemVer standard. Of course no policy is ever perfectly followed, but that's not a sufficient reason not to have a policy.

Comment: @zmbc. That makes sense, but you can always fix the version number for your dependency.

Comment: Fixing version numbers as a package author is a practice that can make things very painful for your users. It makes it much more likely for a user to run into an unsatisfiable set of version constraints.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, there are always some changes between versions, so you will never have "full compatibility". You find all API changes in [API changes](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html) and in the link to "old API changes" within.

But maybe you would just like to continue using matplotlib 2.2.4. In that case the code in the question would look like this:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, mark_inset

x = X = np.linspace(0, 10)
Y1 = np.sin(x) + x + np.random.randn(50)
Y2 = np.sin(x) + 0.4 + np.random.randn(50)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y1,X,Y2)

axins = inset_axes(ax, width="100%", height="100%", 
                   bbox_to_anchor=[0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2], 
                   bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, borderpad=0.0)
axins.plot(X,Y1,X,Y2)

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 1, 0, 2
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

plt.show()
```